# Using F# Result discriminated union results in TypeLoadException

Tags: f#

I've refactored some of my code to use (relatively newly introduced) F# Result type that is defined in FSharp.Core like this:

```
type Result<'TOk,'TError> = 
| Ok of 'TOk 
| Error of 'TError
```

Everything compiles but at runtime the application fails with the following exception:

> Could not load type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpResult`2' from
>   assembly 'SomeAssembly, Version=1.25.24.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' due to value type mismatch.

If I copy the definition to my project so it shadows the original one, everything works.

The app.config has the following section:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <Paket>True</Paket>
    <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.4.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

And the projects files are updated with the directive `<TargetFSharpCoreVersion>4.4.1.0</TargetFSharpCoreVersion>`

So I am not really sure what can cause this error. What is also strange is that the error message claims that FSharpResult is supposed to reside in project assembly, rather than FSharp.Core.dll.

UPDATE. As suggested in the comments, the problem only occurs when the application is built using Visual Studio 2015. Here's a small console program that reproduces the problem:

```
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let result = Result.Ok "Hello"
    printfn "%A" result
    0
```

Open Visual Studio 2015, build and run the project, you should see this error:
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 
'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpResult`2' from assembly 
'ResultTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' due to value type mismatch.
   at Program.main(String[] argv)

If you have Visual Studio 2017 and rebuild the app with it, the app will work fine and prints the result:
Ok "Hello"

Comment: I think you have stale compilation results lying somewhere. Try cleaning out everything and full rebuild.

Comment: Thanks! Will do.

Comment: Nope :-( Didn't help. Cleaned directories, rebuilt everything, same error.

Comment: Well, in that case, you need to see where the error happens, then find an references to `Result` at that place, and then see if any of them actually point to `SomeAssembly`.

Comment: Did that. I don't have Result defined anywhere, so wherever I use it (in a couple of assemblies) I see that it points to Microsoft.FSharp.Core. But at runtime the TypeLoadException is thrown.

Comment: did you nuget Fsharp.Core and are you using MSBuild 15 (in VS2017)?

Comment: I am using VS 2015. In my paket.lock files it's FSharp.Core (4.2.1) that gets listed.

Comment: Can you create a project that reproduces the issue or share an assembly that does on execution?

Comment: I just ran into exactly the same problem! I used fuslogvw to check that the Fsharp.Core.dll was being loaded from the local \bin\ dir, and I also checked that the dll there is the right version, but I'm still getting a TypeLoadException as well.

Comment: With more research, I found the problem (at least for me). I'm using VS2015 and also have F# 4.1 installed separately. I have a project referencing FSharp.Core 4.1.x which I'm developing inside VS2015. 
If I build from the command line using FAKE, the resulting exe (in /bin/release/) works fine. If I build from inside VS2015, it compiles but the resulting exe (in /bin/debug/) has this problem even when run outside of VS. Again, the fusion log shows the debug version loading the correct DLL, so no idea what the problem is. My workaround for now is to run the release version.

Comment: Finally, if I build inside VS2017, the /bin/debug version works as well. So it seems to be some mismatch between VS2015 and F# 4.1

Comment: This is weird. I will try to test it with both VS2015 and VS2017.

Comment: Yes, I confirm that the problem is when you build the code using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is caused by F# 4.0 compiler using together with FSharp.Core 4.4.1.0, as described here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/3354

Workaround: Add FSharp.Compiler.Tools NuGet package to the affected projects as long as Visual Studio 2015 is used. Visual Studio 2017 works fine.

Comment: If I could +100000 this I would. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, using VS2015 IDE was a must, so we implemented our own version of the Result type:

```
type Result<'t, 'e> = | Ok of 't | Error of 'e
```

or you can even fine tune the type with your own error handling requirements, e.g.:

```
type Result<'t> =
        | Success of 't
        | Failure of (string * exn option)
```

or

```
type Result<'t> =
        | Success of 't
        | Failure of (ErrorCode * string)
and ErrorCode = | Code1 | Code2 | Code3
```

I know it's not ideal, it's better if you have this types available in the F# core, but it did the trick :)

Comment: We also did the same.